# Android: Right Handling with multiple Notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I receive Push-Notifications from GCM and want them to be shown in the Notification-Bar. So I generation the Notifications in the GCMIntentService-class.

If there is already a notification in the notification-area, this notification have to be appended with the new message (with use of the BigTextStyle). But how do I know if there is a notification from my app in the notification-area?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get existing notification, but you can update existing notification by setting up Notification ID.

```
NotificationManager.notify(NotificationId, NotificationObject);
```

Comment: Yes, I know but I have to know if the last displayed notification is still being shown. I want to merge my notifications.

Comment: To make this more clear, I give an example:
1. New GCM message "Message 1" arrives. Generate NOtification
2. New GCM message "Message 2" arrives. If the first Notification is still shown, generate a new Notification (with same ID) that contains "Message 1" and "Message 2". Else show only "Message 2".

Comment: I was out for 2 days, but as far as I know it doesnt seem possible. If i found something, i will let you know

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't find out if there's already a notification posted; this is something you should keep track of in your app.

Fortunately, however, the API for updating an existing notification is identical to the API for creating a new one: [`notify()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.app.Notification%29). That is, once you get new information, add it to some internal buffer (possibly just a `StringBuilder`) representing the complete set of received push notifications, then build a new notification with `Notification.Builder` and call `notify()` with the same ID and tag you used last time. Any existing notification with that ID and tag will be replaced with the new content.

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't solve the problem. (See the example in my comment to the first reply). Apparently other apps don't handle this neither.

Comment: You can use the `deleteIntent` to find out when your previous notification is cleared, so from that you should be able to figure out if it's still showing. Does that help?